# Why do some sites not load if cookies are blocked?

Tags: browser, privacy, cookies

As a rule I only allow cookies from sites that require one to logon, and my browsers(Palemoon and Chromium) are set to reject cookies by default, except for a whitelist.

Some sites simply don't load unless you let them set cookies, all I get is a blank page.

Is there a reason why?
Was looking at it from a browser compatibility angle. My question is adequately answered now.

Comment: Are you asking why the sites might be designed to do that, or the coding mechanism that is responsible for it, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, unfortunately, this is just bad development. I've seen a lot of pieces of code related to cookies with no error handling whatsoever regarding disabled cookies. There are 3 cases: websites that need cookies and that will print a page if you have them disabled (that's good), websites that need them but just seem to print an unclear error when you try, and websites that need or don't even need them but fails to handle the case where there are disabled. Depending on the language used for development, it will raise an exception that, if not caught, will lead to a blank page, as debug information is disabled in production mode (if they at least did this).